# node.js Parse success/error not found, response not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-platform

Hi I'm quite new with Parse and Node.js.

When I'm trying to define a function:

```
app.get('/something', function(req, res) {

  var query = new Parse.Query("Something");

  query.find({
    success: function(objects) {
      res.render('something-else', {
        somethings: objects
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I'm met with a Result: success/error was not called

Subsequently when I try to add in the error either by adding res.error or status.error, I get these respective errors:

```
app.get('/something', function(req, res) {

  var query = new Parse.Query("Something");

  query.find({
    success: function(objects) {
      res.render('something-else', {
        somethings: objects
      });
    },
    error: function() {
      res.error("error");
    }
  });
});
```

TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'error'

and for status:

```
app.get('/something', function(req, res) {

  var query = new Parse.Query("Something");

  query.find({
    success: function(objects) {
      res.render('something-else', {
        somethings: objects
      });
    },
    error: function() {
      status.error("error");
    }
  });
});
```

ReferenceError: status is not defined

I understand that that probably means I need to create the status variable somewhere, but where would be a good place to do it and how?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

express' response object does not have a function called "error":

http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.status

Try instead:

```
app.get('/something', function(req, res) {

  var query = new Parse.Query("Something");

  query.find({
    success: function(objects) {
      res.render('something-else', {
        somethings: objects
      });
    },
    error: function(err) {
      res.send(500, err);
    }
  });
});
```